# Firebase Cloud Express queue for storage resource to be generated

Tags: node.js, csv, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a large dataset stored in a Firestore collection and a Nodejs express app (exposed as a firebase functions.https.onRequest) with an endpoint which allows users to query this dataset and download large amounts of data.

I need to return the data in CSV format from the endpoint. Because there is a lot of data, I want to avoid doing large database reads each time the endpoint is hit.

My current endpoint does this:

1. User hits endpoint with a database query requesting documents within a range
2. Query is hashed into a filename. eg query_"startRange"_"endRange".csv
3. Check Firebase storage to see if this query has been run before

if the csv already exists:

1. return a 302 redirect to the csv file with a signed url

if the csv doesn't exist:

1. Run the query on the Firestore collection
2. Transform the data into the appropriate CSV format
3. upload the new CSV to Firebase storage
4. return a 302 redirect to the newly generated csv file with a signed url

This process is currently working really well, except I can already foresee an issue. The CSV generation stage takes roughly 20s for large queries and there is a high possibility of the same request being hit from multiple users at the same time.

I want to build in some sort of queuing system so that if X number of users hit the endpoint at once, only the first request triggers the generation of the new CSV and the other (X-1) requests will be queued and then resolved once the CSV is generated.

I have currently looked into [firebase-queue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-queue) which appears to be deprecated and not intended to be used with Cloud functions.
I have also seen other libraries like [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue) but I'm not sure I understand how that would work with Firebase Cloud functions and how seperate instances are booted for many requests.

Comment: Your problem statement unfortunately doesn't define what should happen if user X kicks off the process but user X+1 tries to get access while X is still running.  It's going to take a significant amount of coding to get this all to work out in a way that works reliably for all access.

Comment: The X+1 request would return a 302 redirect to the CSV file once the X request has finished generating it and uploaded it to storage. Until then the request will be waiting in some sort of queue while the CSV is being generated. I'm wondering if there is some pre-existing method of achieving this in express with firebase cloud, or if I will need to roll my own.

Comment: Please read my comment again - what if the X+1 request happens **during** the X request, given that it takes time to complete, and we don't know how long? This is going to require some amount of synchronization between clients about the state of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a solution similar to what [Happy-Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63410667/12454116) suggested. I'm using the nodejs admin SDK but the idea is similar.

There is a collection in Firestore which keeps track of executed queries `Queries`. When a user hits the endpoint, I call the admin `doc("Queries/<queryId>").create()` method. This method will only create the query doc if it doesn't already exist, so I am able to avoid race conditions between parallel requests if I were to check for existing queries first.

Next the request starts an `onSnapshot` listener to the query that it attempted to created. The query has a `status` field which starts as `created`. The `onSnapshot` will only resolve once that status has changed to `complete`.

I have `onCreate` database trigger listening to "Queries/*". This database trigger handles the requested query and updates the query status to `complete`. In the case that the query already exists, the status is already in the `complete` state, so the `onSnapshot` resolves instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your scenario the queue approach wouldn't work quite well with Cloud Functions. The queue cannot be implemented in a function as multiple instances won't know about each other, therefore the queue would need to be implemented in some kind of dedicated server, which IMO defeats the purpose of using Cloud Functions as both the queue and the processing could be ran in the same server.

I would suggest having a collection in Firestore that keeps track of the queries that have been requested. This way even if the CSV file isn't still saved on Storage you could check if some function instance is already creating it, then you could sleep the function until the operation completes and return the signed url. Overall the algorithm might look somewhat like this:

```py
# Python PseudoCode
if csv_in_storage():
   return signed_url()

if query_in_firestore():
   while True:
      sleep(X)
      if csv_in_storage():
         return signed_url()

try:
   add_query_firestore()
   csv = create_csv()
   upload_csv(csv)
   return signed_url()
except Exception:
   while True:
      sleep(X)
      if csv_in_storage():
         return signed_url()
```

The final try/catch is there because the `add_query_firestore` operation might eventually fail if two functions make simultaneous attempts to write the same document into Firestore. Nonetheless this are also good news since you know the CSV creation is in progress and you can wait for it to complete.

Please keep in mind the pseudocode above is just to illustrate the idea, having the `while True` as it is may lead to infinite loop and function timeout which is plain bad :).